# Errors running geodjango based apps on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, geodjango

**The problem**

I am trying to deploy my geodjango application to Heroku. The application runs but when I try to view either `/admin/world/worldborder/` ([the wolrd geodjango tutorial application](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/)) or my own custom Spots application (which uses geodjango) then the site crashes.

If I look at my `heroku logs` then I see that the dyno experienced a 500 error :

```
2012-07-20T08:16:23+00:00 heroku[router]: GET myapp.herokuapp.com/admin/spots/spot/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=654ms status=500 bytes=4922
```

and then I get this error via email:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GeoSQLCompiler'
```

The full traceback can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/T76QVJHc)

I have my database server on a aws ec2 instance elsewhere and have  gone through [these installation instructions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ubuntu-debian-gnu-linux) on that server.

**App context**

Django==1.4
gunicorn==0.14.2

I created my heroku app with the following

```
heroku create myapp --stack cedar --buildpack http://github.com/cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango/
```

As you see I'm using a [custom buildpack](https://github.com/cirlabs/heroku-buildpack-geodjango) to install all the necessary stuff for geodjango. If I do not use this custom buildpack and simply use `heroku create myapp` then I get [this long error](http://pastebin.com/1DsE8y2J).

I've also added these to the heroku config variables

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH='/app/.geodjango/geos/lib/libgeos_c.so'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/app/.geodjango/gdal/lib/libgdal.so'
```

**What I have tried already**

I googled the error and have only come across one post [here](http://djangosaur.tumblr.com/post/409277054/geodjango-database-engine-for-django-1-2). Bascially says to make sure my database backend is correctly set to use (I have done this)

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
```

I have also tried changing  to  in the following:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH='/myapp/.geodjango/geos/lib/libgeos_c.so'
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/myapp/.geodjango/gdal/lib/libgdal.so'
```

This application works fine on my local dev machine with either `python manage.py runserver` or `foreman start -f Profile.dev`

**Why can I not use my geodjango based apps on Heroku and how can I fix this?**

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: No I didn't. In the end I move my web application to DotCloud. http://docs.dotcloud.com/0.4/tutorials/python/geodjango/

Comment: Heroku seems half-baked for GeoDjango apps. What's your opinion of DotCloud?

Comment: Been so happy. After the pain I went through trying to deploy my app on Heroku DotCloud is a piece of cake. Literally just went through their little tutorial and viola it was up and running. In fact I moved all my web apps to DotCloud. Only thing is that Heroku free tier is a little better I think but not even by that many features.

Comment: And it supports PostGIS?

Comment: Yep. I posted a link in previous comment which shows the geodjango tutorial and explains the PostGIS support. :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 93.2% sure that this is a `path` problem. One of the major [PITAs](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PITA) in web development is that your command line environment may have next to nothing in common with the *server's* environment.

I use the following when I need to know *exactly* what version of which modules are being loaded from what directory. It returns a list of 2-tuples `('name', 'path-to-module')`. Call this after your initialization is completed, or just before and/or after you attempt to load your geo module (or other equally interesting places), and dump the results to the screen or a log file.

I don't know that this will solve your problem, but it may give you some interesting insights.

Note: You can edit (or comment out) the `re.sub()`s to taste. I just put them in because a big page of absolute path names is hard on the eyes and can mask the fact that something is loading from the system's copy of something rather than your own copy of it.

## `modulelist.py`

```
import sys, re, os
import django

def ModuleList():
    ret = []
    dir_project = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    project_name = os.path.basename(dir_project)

    for k,v in sys.modules.items():

        x = str(v)
        if 'built-in' in x:
            ret.append((k, 'built-in'))
            continue

        m = re.search(r"^.*?'(?P<module>.*?)' from '(?P<file>.*?)'.*$", x)
        if m:
            d = m.groupdict()
            f = d['file']
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/.*?/lib/python[.0-9]*/site-packages/django/', 'system django >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/.*?/lib/python[.0-9]*/site-packages/', 'site-packages >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(r'/usr/.*?/lib/python[.0-9]*/', 'system python >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(dir_project+'.*python/', 'local python >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(dir_project+'.*django/', 'local django >> ', f)
            f = re.sub(dir_project+r'(/\.\./)?', project_name + ' >> ', f)
            ret.append((d['module'], f))
    ret.sort( lambda a,b: cmp(a[0].lower(), b[0].lower()) )
    ret.insert(0, ('Python version', sys.version) )
    ret.insert(0, ('Django version', django.get_version()) )

    return ret
# ModuleList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in ModuleList():
        print "%s\t%s" % (x[0], x[1])
```

Comment: Hi Peter I see what you are saying. I'll try pop in this code and see what happens. Even if I click on the link within the admin to go to the app change list though I get my error. Now sure how to hook this into there but perhaps I'll make another simpler view and put this code in there and see what happens.

Comment: In a Django site your modules list normally won't change much when executing one path or another. The only exception is an `import` that occurs in a nested block/def. So you could start by creating a "toy view" that just dumps the output of this routine. This should give you a good first approximation of where things live. Good luck!